# Rserve - Remote connection failed

Tags: r, rserve

I am trying to connect to R from my php application using Rserve.I can successfully execute R commands in my local R server. But when I try to connect to a remote server, it is showing

> unable to connect [0]: No connection could be made because the target
> machine actively refused it

I am created Rserv.conf file in /etc folder. also added the following contents

> remote enable
>
> plaintext enable

I tried by using telnet command also. Firewall is off in my system.
Can you please help to resolve this issue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rserve(args=" --RS-enable-remote")

this worked...